# Apache htaccess spanish accent

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, special-characters

I have a problem with a redirect rule that doesn´t work with spanish special characters. I dont know how can i convert my word to type into the htaccess file, because the charset supported by htaccess file doesn´t recognice de Á, É, etc characters. Do you know can i set the redirect rule for something like:

```bash
Redirect 301 /home/BÁSICO.pdf http://example.com/exampledocument.pdf
```

or

```bash
Redirect 301 /home/MÉDICOS.pdf http://example.com/exampledocument.pdf
```

Comment: Is your file saved with `UTF-8` encoding ?

Comment: I tried, but transform BÁSICO into BÃSICO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also exist other posibility. You can try to change all special characters with this "(.*)" in the RewriteRule.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

If you are editing the .htaccess file with Putty, you can try this with your keyboard: 1)accent key; 2)Shift+(A,E,I,O,U); 3)Space bar

With this method I did a similar redirection works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Unicode is a little tricky - you may be better off with the encoded version:

```bash
Redirect 301 /home/B%C3%81SICO.pdf http://example.com/exampledocument.pdf
Redirect 301 /home/M%C3%89DICOS.pdf http://example.com/exampledocument.pdf
```

You can use this encode for assistance: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

<sub>Note: I have not tested this, but it is based off [this question/answer](/q/16347560/1626250).</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot, but after try that, i´ve got  301 412 errors on httpd log but getting the spected URL with the Unicode characters... Have you any idea of why? maybe do i need to add a "\"???